# Xamarin.Mac - TableView sorting by selecting option from dropdown

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have implemented the TableView sorting when table header is clicked. We have another requirement to sort the table data by different options e.g. Name, Date, Size. I am looking for a way to show a dropdown where user can select a type and then sorting happens based on the type selected just like in finder:

[image]

Right now my interface looks like:

[image]

How do I achieve this in table header?

Comment: You want to show a menu when they click on the table header to give sorting options ?

Comment: Yes, I want to show a menu.